# Raspbian Jessie: What do "service --status-all" and "systemctl list-units --type=service" show?

Tags: raspbian, services, init.d, systemd, init

So, I read a lot about init systems in the last two hours, since this topic was completely new to me.

I now know that *Raspbian Jessie* uses *SystemD*. I also found out that `systemctl list-units --type=service` shows me a list of all *SystemD services* defined (services in /etc/systemd/system), which works fine as expected on my system.

On the other hand, I thougth that `service --status-all` shows all *SysV services*. Since *Jessi* uses *SystemD*, I thought that this would not even work, or return an empty list, but it also shows a good amount of services. I checked the /etc/init.d directory (which should store *SysV services*), which has a lot of files in it.

**Question 1:** Why does `service --status-all` show services, even though *SystemD* is the init system, and not *SysV*?

**Question 2:** Why is there a /etc/init.d directory, even though *SystemD* is the init system (whichs services are defined in /etc/systemd/system), and not *SysV*?

Comment: One word - compatibility.

Comment: "...I now know that Raspbian Jessie uses systemd..." only by _default_ you still have the Debian provided option to use an alternative should you wish, and it is possible to prevent the change away from the 30-odd year old System V `init`when upgrading from Debian/Raspian "Wheezy" to "Jessie"... 8-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are for SysV compatibility, which traditionally has been the most widespread init system used on GNU/Linux since its inception. I believe SysV scripts also have a degree of compatibility with BSD init, used on other contemporary [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) operating systems.  While none of that is actually part of the POSIX specification, some commonplace cross-platform software targeting a particular (linux, BSD) side of the family make use of it.

Although systemd has been around for about half a dozen years, it is only in the past 1-2 that it has become the predominant one used in the GNU/Linux world, after Debian gave up on SysV with version 8 and Ubuntu abandoned Upstart.

On Fedora, which started using systemd as the default 5 years ago, there is very little left in `/etc/init.d` but it does remain, together with a `README` which notes:

> ...traditional init scripts continue to function on a systemd
>   system. An init script /etc/rc.d/init.d/foobar is implicitly mapped
>   into a service unit foobar.service during system initialization.

Commands like `service` are also implemented, although things like `update-rc.d`, which I think was a Debianism to start with, are not -- except on Debian (and derivatives including Raspbian).  These Debian things like `update-rc.d` may remain indefinitely or may disappear in the next version or so, but I expect that systemd's implementation of more core SysV commands like `service` are permanent.

The current `/etc/init.d/README` on Raspbian is still the old Debian one.  The Fedora one also includes this link which may be of interest:

https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/

Beware that while `systemctl list-units` will show everything, `service ---status-all` only applies to this that are managed via an `init.d` script.  There are various `systemctl` commands that have parallels to `service --status-all`:

- `systemctl list-units [--type=service]`: Will show all "active" units (note if you read the key at the end, there are two contexts for the word "active").
- `systemctl list-units --all`: Will show all available units.
- `systemctl list-unit-files`: Similiar to the above, but simplified.
- `systemctl status`: Used with no service name, this shows a process tree of everything descended from an init service -- which since all processes have parents except init itself, means all running processes.  This makes it similar to `pstree`, but organized using the concept of "slice" groupings (see `man systemd.slice`).

All this is explained further in `man systemctl`.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. Also for the additional link. One last thing: Do you know if it's planned to remove `service` in the future? Because I like `service --status-all`'s output more than `systemctl list-units --type=service`

Comment: I don't know but I would guess if they intend to support `/etc/init.d` then `service` will continue to exist.  However, as per the man page, beware it applies *only* to actual SysV scripts, whereas `systemctl` should apply to anything actually started as a unit by systemd.  E.g, my Fedora desktop only has two things in `init.d` and that's all `service --status-all` mentions.

Comment: There is a bit of a difference in those commands though; `service` is applied to everything with a file, even if it isn't being used.  A correlate to that might be `systemctl list-unit-files`, except I presume that won't include unused init.d files, since those won't be "mapped into a service unit ... during system initialization".  It would be all unused existent systemd units.  I.e., there's nothing which covers everything, although `systemctl list-units` should cover everything actually in use.

Comment: Also, `systemctl status`, which gives a comprehensive tree of running processes related to init services (and every running process is, one way or another), may be more equivalent than `systemctl list-units`.

Comment: And that perfectly completes the answer, thank you again, helped & I learned a lot!

Comment: As a die-hard Sys V `init` user (even on my RPis running Jessie!) I would note that the output from `service --status-all` which runs the `/usr/sbin/service` shell script may be a little buggy in that the definitive `[ + ]  $SERVICE` and `[ - ]  $SERVICE` outputs are sent to standard output but the unknown `[ ? ]  $SERVICE` output is sent to standard error - which might confuse things for a super-user script interpreting the output...!